# ErrorException: Undefined variable $tareas_choicess in file

Tags: php, laravel

La variable esta definida pero aun así me da el error de variable indefinida "**ErrorException: Undefined variable $tareas_choicess in file**", como lo puedo solucionar ?

```
   public static function getTareasPorCartera($id_cartera)
   {   
      $config = ResponseHelper::getCustomConfig();
      $status = $config['tipo_estado'];
      $anio = date('Y');
      $mes = date('m');

      $tareas = DB::table('tareas')
      ->join('clientes', 'tareas.id_cliente', '=', 'clientes.id')
      ->join('usuarios', 'tareas.user_reg','=','usuarios.id')
      ->select('clientes.id', 'clientes.nombres', 'tareas.fecha_reg','tareas.fecha_tarea','tareas.tarea','usuarios.username','tareas.id_estado')
         ->where('tareas.id_estado',$status)
         ->where('tareas.fecha_tarea','>=', $anio.'-'.$mes.'-01 00:00:00')
         ->where('tareas.id_cartera', $id_cartera)
         ->orderBy('tareas.fecha_tarea')->get();

      foreach($tareas as $t){
         $tareas_choices[] = array($t->id, $t->nombres, $t->fecha_reg,$t->fecha_tarea,$t->tarea, $t->username, $t->id_estado);
      }
      return $tareas_choices;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es por el `SCOPE` declara tu variable `$tareas_choices` antes del `for`.

```php
$tareas_choices = array();
foreach($tareas as $t){
    $tareas_choices = array($t->id, $t->nombres, $t->fecha_reg,$t->fecha_tarea,$t->tarea, $t->username, $t->id_estado);
}
return $tareas_choices;
```

Comment: Gracias eso era, ya pude solucionarlo.

Comment: Recuerda marcar tu pregunta como resuelta por si alguien mas tiene esa duda.